# How do you release Microservices?

Tags: microservices, release-management

The question is tied more to CI/CD practices and infrastructure. In the release we follow, we club a set of microservices docker image tags as a single release, and do CI/CD pipeline and promote that version.yaml to staging and production - say a sort of Mono-release pattern. The problem with this is that at one point we need to serialize and other changes have to wait, till a mono-release is tested and tagged as ready for the next stage.A little more description regarding this [here](https://medium.com/better-software/microservice-release-management-6299c0610264?source=friends_link&sk=9563ffbff92fa866c2cc179c1975c33d).

An alternate would be the micro-release strategy, where each microservice release in parallel through production through the CI/CD pipeline. But then would this mean that there would be as many pipelines as there are microservices? An alternate could have a single pipeline, but parallel test cases and a polling CD - sort of like GitOps way which takes the latest production tagged Docker images.

There seems precious little information regarding the way MS is released. Most talk about interface level or API level versioning and releasing, which is not really what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your organization is developing services in microservices architecture and is deploying in a kubernetes cluster, you must use some CD tool (continuous delivery tool) to release new microservices services, or even update a microservice.

Take a look in tools like Jenkins (https://www.jenkins.io), DroneIO (https://drone.io)... Some organizations use Python scripts, or Go and so on...  I, personally, do not like this approch, I think the best solution is to pick a tool from CNCF Landscape (https://landscape.cncf.io/zoom=150) in Continuous Integration & Delivery group, these are tools test and used in the market.

> **An alternate would be the micro-release strategy, where each microservice release in parallel through production through the CI/CD pipeline. But then would this mean that there would be as many pipelines as there are microservices?**

It's ok in some tools you have a parameterized pipeline thats build projects based in received parameters, but I think the best solution is to have one pipeline per service, and some parameterized pipelines to deploy, or apply specific tests, archive assets and so on... Like you say *micro-release strategy*

Comment: well the question is not about tools ,we use Jenkins,Git,helm ArgoCD etc. Say if you have a 100 or 1000 microservices, how do you release management, which means, how you do testing, group together as a single monolith and test or per service. The latter would have resource challenges

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, there is little information about this out there. From all I understand the approach to keep one pipeline per service sounds reasonable. With a growing amount of microservices you will run into several problems:

- how do you keep track of changes in the configuration
- how do you test your services efficiently with regression and integration tests
- how do you efficiently setup environments

The key here is most probably that you make better use of parameterized environment variables that you then look to version in an efficient manner. This will allow you to keep track of the changes in an efficient manner. To achieve this make sure to a.) strictly paramterize all variables in the container configs and the code and b.) organize the config variables in a way that allows you to inject them at runtime. [This is a piece of content](https://humanitec.com/blog/handling-environment-variables-with-kubernetes) that I found helpful in regard to my point a.); 
As for point b.) this is slightly more tricky. As it looks you are using Kubernetes so you might just want to pick something like helm-charts. The question is how you structure your config files and you have two options:

- Use something like Kustomize which is a configuration management tool that will allow you to version to a certain degree following a GitOps approach. This comes (in my biased opinion) with a good amount of flaws. Git is ultimately not meant for configuration management, it's hard to follow changes, to build diffs, to identify the relevant history if you handle that amount of services.
- You use a Continuous Delivery API (I work for one so make sure you question this sufficiently). CDAPIs connect to all your systems (CI pipelines, clusters, image registries, external resources (DBs, file storage), internal resources (elastic, redis) etc. They dynamically inject environment variables at run-time and create the manifests with each deployment. They cache these as so called "deployment sets". Deployment Sets are the representation of the state of an environment at deployment time. This approach has several advantages: It allows you to share, version, diff and relaunch any state any service and application were in at any given point in time. It provides a very clear and bullet proof audit auf anything in the setup. QA environments or test-feature environments can be spun of through the API or UI allowing for fully featured regression and integration tests.